# Convert Listview subitem string to currency

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a listview with subitems and in one of the subs I need to make the value displayed a currency. The code I am using errors with 'conversion from string "N2" to type 'integer'  is not valid'. I know I need to format the sub, but I am not sure how to do this.

I would be grateful if someone could point out the right way to code this. Many thanks

```
Sub filllistview()
        Try
            'creatconn()
            cn.Open()
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select * from Postings", cn)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While dr.Read()

                ListView1.Items.Add(dr(4).ToString())
                ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(11).ToString())
                ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(7).ToString())
                ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(5).ToString())
                ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(14).ToString())
                ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(dr(3).ToString("N2")) <--- **This is the subitem**

            End While

        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            dr.Close()
            cn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dr(3)` returns the `Object` type. Cast it to integer first:

```
ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(CInt(dr(3)).ToString("C"))
```

Comment: I need that to be currency. It seems that is converting to int. How do I display currency, like £23.56 Thanks